# How to keep track of a pointer passing from one function to another in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Please consider:

```
void bar (int* ptr3)  
{  
    printf ("\n*ptr3 =%d\n",*ptr3);  
}  

void foo (int* ptr2)  
{  
    *ptr2 +=5;  
    bar (ptr2);  
}  

int main()  
{  
    int numb = 5;  
    int *ptr = &numb;  

    foo (ptr);  

    printf("\nHello !!!\n");  

    return 0;  
}
```

Is it possible to track `ptr`, in such a way that at some point I can find out the backtrace of the variable, something like:

```
bar() : ptr3
foo() : *ptr2 +=5; 
main(): int *ptr = &numb;
```

Roughly: Can we get the pointer history in gdb through some way.

Actually, this can help in fixing Memory Leaks/UMR's reported through Purify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, as in your example `ptr3 == ptr2 == ptr == &numb`, so what exactly do you mean by 'pointer history'?

It appears that you are asking to track the changes to the *value* that `ptr` points to (i.e. changes to `numb`). You *can* do that with GDB [watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

Comment: Not tracking the value. But to view the backtraces (corresponding to the pointer variable) at any point of time. Is it possible? -- Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I am utterly failing to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Suppose ptr is passed as follows: func1 { *ptr defined, func2_called(ptr) } .......... func2 (*ptr) { modifies the value & pass ptr to func3(). Is it possible to do backtrace on PTR itself, to get a trace like: func3() -->func2()-->func(1).